# Pi won't start Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, troubleshooting

I am completely new to Raspberry Pi and Raspbian. I needed to access a file from root so i followed [this guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=48293) and in a terminal went

> sudo su
>
> startx

I then logged off the root account and then shut down the Pi normally. Now when I try to boot the Pi I get this error message before the screen goes blank.

Now I don't know how to access my files anymore. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

**Edit** I have added the permissions below
[image]

Comment: Have you tried opening a virtual terminal ctrl+alt+F2. Assuming that works what are the permissions and ownership of /home/raspbian/.Xauthority you can get that info using the following command ls -la /home/raspbian. Please edit your question and add the above.

Comment: Try without "sudo su",  see what it says.

Comment: @SteveRobillard I have posted the permissions by logging into root and following your instructions. I can't have more than 2 pictures in my question so I had to delete the other one

Comment: ok, try this: access the virtual terminal again. then cd /home/raspbian/ then touch .Xauthority then change ownership of the new file to root by doing chown root:root .Xauthority you can read more here http://askubuntu.com/questions/165921/error-on-boot-12-04/166115#166115.

Comment: Ok, i've done that while logged in as root

Comment: If you did the above you should be able to startx as root. I am guessing that the owner of the file should be root, but it may need to be raspbian. So you may want to try chown raspbian:raspbian .Xauthority

Comment: awesome, I am now able to access the GUI as root but my files are in the raspbian username. Is there anyway to now somehow log into the raspbian account so I can access my files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem. Turns out the problem was caused by corrupt .Xauthority files. I fixed this by first logging on as root. I then ran the following command:

`rm .Xauth*`

This deleted all the .Xauthority files that were causing the pi not to boot. A simple shutdown command and restarting the Pi solved the problem.

`shutdown -h now`